# Generic method to iterate over collection (slice) of structs

Tags: go

I have following code in Go:

```
type Foo struct { Id int }
type Bar struct { Id int }

func getIdsFoo(foos []Foo) {
  ids = make([]int, len(foos))
  // iterate and get all ids to ids array
}

func getIdsBar(bars []Bar) {
  ids = make([]int, len(bars))
  // iterate and get all ids to ids array
}
```

Is there a clever way to create a function `getIds([]Idable)` that can take any struct that have method `GetId()` implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sort](http://golang.org/pkg/sort/) uses a design patter that might help you.

Create a function that works on an *slice-like* interface. Then create new types based off of a slice of your concrete types.

Hopefully, the code is more clear than my description. http://play.golang.org/p/TL6yxZZUWT

```
type IdGetter interface {
    GetId(i int) int
    Len() int
}

func GetIds(ig IdGetter) []int {
    ids := make([]int, ig.Len())
    for i := range ids {
        ids[i] = ig.GetId(i)
    }
    return ids
}

type Foo struct{ Id int }

type Bar struct{ Id int }

type FooIdGetter []Foo

func (f FooIdGetter) GetId(i int) int {
    return f[i].Id
}

func (f FooIdGetter) Len() int {
    return len(f)
}

type BarIdGetter []Bar

func (b BarIdGetter) GetId(i int) int {
    return b[i].Id
}

func (b BarIdGetter) Len() int {
    return len(b)
}

func main() {
    var f = []Foo{{5}, {6}, {7}}
    var b = []Bar{{10}, {11}, {12}}

    fmt.Println("foo ids:", GetIds(FooIdGetter(f)))
    fmt.Println("bar ids:", GetIds(BarIdGetter(b)))
}
```

There is still a bit more boilerplate than is pleasant, (Go generics... someday). It's greatest advantage is that new methods do not need to be added to `Foo`, `Bar`, or any future type you may need to work with.

Comment: Why downvote? Its a perfect anwser. Only think I need is to write generators and it will work :) Is there any posibility of using embeding here to avoid generating `Len()` and `GetId()` over and over again?

Answer (score 3):

```
type Identifiable interface {
    GetId() int
}

func GatherIds(ys []Identifiable) []int {
    xs := make([]int, 0, len(ys))
    for _, i := range ys {
        xs = append(xs, i.GetId())
    }
    return xs
}
```

Comment: `[]Foo` cannot be cast to `[]Identifiable`, even if `Foo` implements the `Identifiable` interface.

Comment: Typo: `append(xs, i)` => `append(xs, i.GetId())`

Comment: @deft_code I noticed that it can't be cast becouse it is O(n) operation, but is it true? Do you have some reading about it?